# How can I make my contour wrap around in a map projection of data?

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I have a model that I am using to generate values across an array of latitudes and longitudes that go from -180 -> +180 degrees longitude and -90 -> +90 degrees latitude with 100 increments for each. When I plot the Mollewide projection map and the maps of the northern and southern hemispheres, the data looks continuous with the exception of the line of 0 degrees latitude. Oddly enough, the Mollewide projection looks continuous at this point but the hemisphere projections show a discontinuity there. Is there any way to "wrap" the data to make the contour lines and data look continuous?

Here is the Mollewide projection:

[image: mollewide]

Here are the hemisphere projections:

[image: hemispheres]

And here is the code I used (I got ride of the unnecessary lines for annotating the map)

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,10))
ax = plt.subplot(311)
m = Basemap(projection='moll',lon_0=0,resolution='c')
m.contour(lon,lat,dat, 9, colors='k',latlon=True,linewidths=0.5)
a = m.contourf(lon,lat,dat, levels=np.linspace(0,10,100),vmin=0,vmax=100,extend='both', cmap=reversed_color_map,latlon=True)
m.drawparallels(np.arange(-90,90,30),labels=[0,0,0,0])
m.drawmeridians(np.arange(-180,180,30),labels=[0,0,0,0],zorder=100,)

ax1 = plt.subplot(321)
m = Basemap(projection='npstere',lon_0=0,resolution='c',boundinglat=25,round=True)
m.contour(lon,lat,dat, 8, colors='k',latlon=True,linewidths=0.5)
m.contourf(lon,lat,dat, levels=np.linspace(0,10,100),vmin=0,vmax=100,extend='both', cmap=reversed_color_map,latlon=True)
m.drawparallels(np.arange(-90,90,30),labels=[0,0,0,0])

plt.subplot(322)
m = Basemap(projection='spstere',lon_0=0,resolution='c',boundinglat=-25,round=True)
m.contour(lon[:,:-1],lat[:,:-1],dat[:,:-1], 8, colors='k',latlon=True,linewidths=0.5)
m.contourf(lon,lat,dat, levels=np.linspace(0,10,100),vmin=0,vmax=100,extend='both', cmap=reversed_color_map,latlon=True)
m.drawparallels(np.arange(-90,90,30),labels=[0,0,0,0])
m.drawmeridians(np.arange(0,360,30),labels=[0,0,0,0],zorder=100,)
```

Comment: Please explain this "`the data looks continuous with the exception of the line of 0 degrees latitude`". How is it not continuous?

Comment: In the first figure, the contour line at 0 degrees longitude and between 30 and 60 degrees latitude is continuous. But in the bottom left figure, that same contour line approaches 0 degrees longitude from the left and ends abruptly.

Comment: Try skipping the lines `m.drawmeridians()` and check again. The contour lines might be hidden under the meridians.